# Setting Cinterion BGS2-W modem certificates in code

Tags: c, ssl, embedded, at-command

I'm trying to use AT commands to setup a BGS2-W modem on a custom board to connect to a site over TLS, but the modem is not reacting to my commands and no certificates are being set.

I'm using the command

```
AT^SBNW
```

to send the commands as documented in Transport Layer Security for Client
TCP/IP Services doc (https://ptelectronics.ru/wp-content/uploads/organizatsiya_bezopasnogo_ssl-soedineniya.pdf#page=8).

Unfortunately, the document provides no examples, and I haven't been able to find any samples showing the usage of this command online.

The document linked has a java commandline tool attached that will send a cert from a PC, however I am unable to use this tool (I don't have the connection to the modem).

If anyone has any idea's on how to use this command I could very much use the help.

Note: I'm trying to set the certificates from within code running on a PIC18 - this isn't a final incarnation, I just need the certificates loaded so I can connect to our secure server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guess this one isn't going to find an answer anytime soon :)

So, its fairly easy to capture the output from the javatool - I'm using Com0Com to emulate 2 connected ports, then using termite to manually input on one port while telling the java app to connect to the other.

The first query from the java app expects an "OK" response, I find it easiest to send the response before starting the java app (I guess it gets cached in the recv buffer of the emulated port).

The javatool then sends "AT^SBNW=is_cert,1\r", and you can type in the reply in termite "SECURE CMD READY: SEND COMMAND ..."

After this a large binary dump comes through.  You can decode the dump using the structure described in Application Note 62 (https://ptelectronics.ru/wp-content/uploads/organizatsiya_bezopasnogo_ssl-soedineniya.pdf).  That should get all the data required to generate the same binary within code.